# MYSQL - Huge issue getting current item usign Group BY

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a lot of trouble with mysql queries and Group BY :

```
select MIN(price) AS price , date(x_date) AS date , id AS id
from tableX 
group by week(x_date)
```

This returns :

```
[{"price":900.42,"date":"2017-01-05","id":2366},
{"price":789.4,"date":"2017-01-08","id":2369},
{"price":820.53,"date":"2017-01-15","id":2376},
{"price":889.88,"date":"2017-01-22","id":2383},
{"price":917.14,"date":"2017-01-29","id":2390},
{"price":991.02,"date":"2017-02-05","id":2397},
{"price":998.18,"date":"2017-02-12","id":2404},
{"price":1055.62,"date":"2017-02-19","id":2411}
```

**The prices are being grouped correctly by the minimum price for that week , however the date & id it is returning is wrong . I'm getting the first date & id of that week instead of the date where the minimum price occurred .**

Full json :

```
select price AS price , date(x_date) AS date , id AS id
from tableX
```

---

```
[{"price":1067.84,"date":"2017-01-05","id":2366},
{"price":950.74,"date":"2017-01-06","id":2367},
{"price":900.42,"date":"2017-01-07","id":2368},
{"price":909.35,"date":"2017-01-08","id":2369},
{"price":906.43,"date":"2017-01-09","id":2370},
{"price":902.07,"date":"2017-01-10","id":2371},
{"price":840.38,"date":"2017-01-11","id":2372},
{"price":789.4,"date":"2017-01-12","id":2373},
{"price":814.48,"date":"2017-01-13","id":2374},
{"price":822.38,"date":"2017-01-14","id":2375},
{"price":820.53,"date":"2017-01-15","id":2376},
{"price":826.34,"date":"2017-01-16","id":2377},
{"price":867.36,"date":"2017-01-17","id":2378},
{"price":894.35,"date":"2017-01-18","id":2379},
{"price":891.13,"date":"2017-01-19","id":2380},
{"price":894.82,"date":"2017-01-20","id":2381},
{"price":905.82,"date":"2017-01-21","id":2382},
{"price":922.67,"date":"2017-01-22","id":2383},
{"price":919.01,"date":"2017-01-23","id":2384},
{"price":899.17,"date":"2017-01-24","id":2385},
{"price":889.88,"date":"2017-01-25","id":2386},
{"price":904.61,"date":"2017-01-26","id":2387},
{"price":916.83,"date":"2017-01-27","id":2388},
{"price":919.42,"date":"2017-01-28","id":2389},
{"price":917.16,"date":"2017-01-29","id":2390},
{"price":917.14,"date":"2017-01-30","id":2391},
{"price":943.95,"date":"2017-01-31","id":2392},
{"price":977.51,"date":"2017-02-01","id":2393},
{"price":997.57,"date":"2017-02-02","id":2394},
{"price":1012.95,"date":"2017-02-03","id":2395},
{"price":1025.88,"date":"2017-02-04","id":2396},
{"price":1023.82,"date":"2017-02-05","id":2397},
{"price":1019.3,"date":"2017-02-06","id":2398},
{"price":1038.57,"date":"2017-02-07","id":2399},
{"price":1053.44,"date":"2017-02-08","id":2400},
{"price":1021.64,"date":"2017-02-09","id":2401},
{"price":991.02,"date":"2017-02-10","id":2402},
{"price":1001.54,"date":"2017-02-11","id":2403},
{"price":1004.75,"date":"2017-02-12","id":2404},
{"price":998.18,"date":"2017-02-13","id":2405},
{"price":1003.06,"date":"2017-02-14","id":2406},
{"price":1009.18,"date":"2017-02-15","id":2407},
{"price":1021.6,"date":"2017-02-16","id":2408},
{"price":1043.6,"date":"2017-02-17","id":2409},
{"price":1055.76,"date":"2017-02-18","id":2410},
{"price":1055.62,"date":"2017-02-19","id":2411},
{"price":1068.03,"date":"2017-02-20","id":2412},
{"price":1103.45,"date":"2017-02-21","id":2413},
{"price":1122.93,"date":"2017-02-22","id":2414},
{"price":1150.29,"date":"2017-02-23","id":2415},
{"price":1179.65,"date":"2017-02-24","id":2416},
{"price":1166.25,"date":"2017-02-25","id":2417},
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT MAINTABLE.*     
   FROM TABLEX MAINTABLE INNER JOIN
    (
         SELECT PRICE , DATE(X_DATE) AS DATE , ID AS ID
         FROM TABLEX 
         GROUP BY WEEK(X_DATE)
    ) INNERTABLE ON MAINTABLE.ID = INNERTABLE.ID AND MAINTABLE.X_DATE = INNERTABLE.DATE
```

Try above query.